# Why Does "GET" Override "SESSION"

Tags: php, get

In the code:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['id'] = 14;
    if(isset($_GET['id']))
    {
        $id = $_GET['id'];
    }
    else
    {
        $id = $_SESSION['id'];
    }
    echo $id;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $_SESSION['id'];
?>
```

Why is the second value echoed out always equal the GET variable (assuming there is one set)? Is this a misconfiguration or am I missing something?

Comment: I'm assuming they're not both coincidentally 14? Is this the actual code you are running?

Comment: So are you saying that `echo $_SESSION['id'];` is echoing the same as `echo $id;` even if `$_GET['id'] != 14`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My magic crystal ball says that you have the [register_globals](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) setting turned on. check it by calling `phpinfo()`

When `register_globals` is on, `$foo` and `$_SESSION['foo']` are [references](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php) to each other, but only if $foo is in the global scope. This means assigning a value to either of them, causes the other to update. Think of them as being the exact same variable.

That setting is ancient. If I remember correctly, the references between $foo and $_SESSION['foo'] will only be established after one of:

1. immediately after calling session_start() IF $_SESSION['foo'] existed in the session.
2. immediately after assigning any value to $_SESSION['foo']
3. immediately after calling session_register('foo')

You should strongly consider disabling register_globals. unexpected program behavior just like this is the very reason the setting was discouraged, and eventually totally removed from php.

Comment: Thank you! This explains my extremely odd issue :)